# How to calculate the limit of a recursively defined sequence?

Tags: limits, recursion

[image]

My attempt:

(i) For r=1, $x_n$ = n+1 $\iff$ $\frac{n+1}{1+1/n}$ = $x_{n-1}$ $\iff$ $\frac{n(n+1)}{n+1}$ = $x_{n-1}$ $\iff$ n = $x_{n-1}$

But I don't know how to use what I have shown so far to show that $x_n$ = n+1

(ii) $$\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = (r+0) \ell = r\ell $$

I know this is the wrong answer, but I'm not sure what else to try.

Comment: For the first one, try using induction;
For the second, note that $\lim x_n=\lim x_{n-1}$ given that the limit exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have the recursive relationship $x_n=\left(r+\frac1n\right)x_{n-1}$, with initial condition $x_0=1$.   For $r=1$, we have $x_n=\left(1+\frac1n\right)x_{n-1}=\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)x_{n-1}$.

Thus, we can generate the solution recursively as

$$x_n=\frac{n+1}{n} \frac{n}{n-1} \frac{n-1}{n-2}\cdots \frac{4}{3}\frac32 \frac21=n+1$$

as expected!

---

Alternatively, we can use induction.  We see that $x_1=2$ and $x_2=3$.  So, we assume that for some $k$, $x_k=k+1$.   Then,

$x_{k+1}=\frac{k+2}{k+1}\times x_k=k+2$

which completes the proof.

---

For part $(2)$, we assume that $\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n=L$.  Then,

$$x_n=\left(r+\frac1n\right)x_{n-1}\implies L=rL\implies r=1\,\,\text{or}\,\,L=0$$

Since we already showed that $x_n$ has no limit if $r=1$, then we conclude that $L=0$.